# React Beautiful DnD not working in React Typescript Project

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I've created a new React project with Typescript, using create React app - and now I want to add a drag and drop functionality.

Basically, I am building an elaborate todo list, but at this point, it is still super simple (just in case anyone was wondering about the code-splitting).

However, for the app to actually hold any real value, I need to make each task drag-and-droppable within a list, so I have tried to install the React Beautiful DnD library and followed along this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEVHJf30bWI

But it is not working.

FIY I haven't completed the entire video, because at the point where he says: "And now you should be able to drag and drop your items" my items are locked tight, so no need to continue, before I solve that issue.

This is my app.tsx file

```
import { MyLogin, MyRegistration, RootLayout, Home, Content } from "./pages";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> },
      { path: "/Content", element: <Content /> },
      { path: "/Login", element: <MyLogin /> },
      { path: "/register", element: <MyRegistration /> },
    ],
  },
]);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={() => {}}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </DragDropContext>
    </main>
  );
};
export default App;
```

This is my Home.tsx file (this list should appear on the home screen):

```
import { ContentBox, PageTitle, List } from "../components/UI";
export const Home = () => {
  return (
    <ContentBox>
      <PageTitle title="Choose Activity" />
      <List/>
    </ContentBox>
  );
};
```

This is List.tsx

```
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { IconCard } from "./index";
import styles from "../../styles/UI/List.module.css";

export const List = () => {
  const classList = `${styles.list}`;
  const items = [
    { image: { src: "./shopping-cart.png", alt: "" }, title: "one", id: "1" },
    { image: { src: "./shopping-cart.png", alt: "" }, title: "one", id: "2" },
    { image: { src: "./shopping-cart.png", alt: "" }, title: "one", id: "3" },
  ];
  return (
    <Droppable droppableId="list">
      {(provided) => (
        <ul
          className={classList}
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.droppableProps}
        >
          {items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <IconCard
                image={{ src: item.image.src, alt: item.image.alt }}
                title={item.title}
                id={item.id}
                index={index}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
    </Droppable>
  );
};
```

This is IconCard.tsx

```
import styles from "../../styles/UI/Card.module.css";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

export const IconCard = ({
  image,
  title,
  text,
  id,
  index,
}: {
  image: { src: string; alt: string };
  title: string;
  text?: string;
  id: string;
  index: number;
}) => {
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={index.toString()} index={index}>
      {(provided) => (
        <div
          className={styles.card}
          key={id}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
          ref={provided.innerRef}
        >
          <div className={styles.imageWrapper}>
            <img src={image.src} alt={image.alt} />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>{title}</p>
            {text && <p>{text}</p>}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
};
```

I have tried to collect all "parts" in just one file, to see if it was due to code-splitting, but with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I just removed the Strict mode and now drag and drop functionality works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).